How to send photos to server in flask?
I am developing a website. I am getting user uploaded photo and sending it to flask back end to process. If everything goes through, the photos will be added to database, and redirect to a home page. Since user can upload photos multiple times, and may delete photos. I use an array to capture the updated photos.
project
|
|___app
|   |
|   |___templates
|   |   |
|   |   |__postAd.html
|   |   |___index.html
|   |
|   |__postAd.py
|   
|
|__main.py

postAd.html
<form
    method="POST"
    class="needs-validation"
    novalidate
    id="form"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
    action="{{url_for('postAd.post_ad',category=category,subcategory=subcategory)}}"
  >
<input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFileMultiple" name="photo" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" multiple="multiple"/>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">file support:jpg,jpeg,png</div>
      <output class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3"
        id="result">
      </output>
<button id="submit-button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
<script>
var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-button");
form.addEventListener(
  "submit",
  function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();    
    if (!form.checkValidity()) {
      form.classList.add("was-validated");
    } 
    else {
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to post the ad?")) {       
        sendPhotosToServer();
        form.submit();              
      }
    }
  },
  false
);
const imageInput = document.getElementById("formFileMultiple");
const output = document.querySelector("#result");
const uploadedPhotos = [];
imageInput.addEventListener("change", handleImageUpload);

function handleImageUpload(e) {
  const files = Array.from(e.target.files);
  const number_of_images = files.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < number_of_images; i++) {    
    uploadedPhotos.push(files[i]);
    const picReader = new FileReader();
    picReader.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
      const imgContainer = document.createElement("div");
      imgContainer.className = "col";
      imgContainer.innerHTML = `<div class="card">
                            <div class="image-container">
                                <img src="${event.target.result}" alt="${files[i].name}" class="card-img-top" style="height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete-btn">Delete</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    `;
      const deleteBtn = imgContainer.querySelector(".delete-btn");
      deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        imgContainer.remove();
        const index = uploadedPhotos.indexOf(files[i]);
        if (index > -1) {
          uploadedPhotos.splice(index, 1); // Remove the file from the array
        }
      });
      output.appendChild(imgContainer);      
    });
    picReader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
  } 
}

async function sendPhotosToServer() {
  const formData = new FormData();

  // Append each photo from uploadedPhotos array to the form data
  uploadedPhotos.forEach((photo, index) => {
    formData.append(`photo_${index}`, photo);
  });
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`/post-ads/${category}/${subcategory}`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const result = await response.json();
      console.log("Photos uploaded successfully!", result);
    } else {
      console.log("Failed to upload photos.", response.status);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during photo upload:", error);
    console.log("An error occurred while uploading photos.");
  }
}
</script>

postAd.py
@postAd.route("/post-ads/<category>/<subcategory>", methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def post_ad(category,subcategory):
response = render_template("postAd.html",category=category,subcategory=subcategory))
   if request.method == 'POST':
      photos = request.files.getlist('photo')
      ad = Ad(photos=photos)
      db.session.add(ad)
      db.session.commit()
      flash('post ad successfully!','success')
      return redirect(url_for('index.html'))
   return response

Each ad belongs to a category, subcategory. The photos are shown in browser, and each photo has a delete button. When I submit the form, the postAd never gets the photo in uploadedPhotos. It only gets the user last uploaded photos in browser. The console in development tool says Error during photo upload: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.An error occurred while uploading photos. The network tab shows the fetch request is blocked with NS_binding aborted under transferred. It seems the error is related to network security. But I'm still in development, so everything uses http instead of https. Is there a way to get around this?

You are not awaiting the result of sendPhotosToServer(). It's async and returns a Promise. form.submit() cancels that request before it completes, hence the error.

Got it, I realized the issue and already fixed it. I added window.location.href=response.url to handle the server redirect. But the flashed message never display in the redirect page as the tradition form submission.

@kevin did you manage to solve your problem? If so, consider adding an answer detailing your solution so others might have access to the resource. If you still need help, let us know what's going on so we can further assist :)

I figured out the solution. The database did not receive all the variables. So I included all variables user typed in the form and sent a post request to back end. Also, adding async and await to fetch function to fulfil the promise until server sent a response @jp-jee mentioned.
